# retrieve all issued JWT tokens

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

how can I retrieve all issued tokens for a certain user in Node JS ? 
I have checked the database but it does not contain any collection document that list these tokens

I am also wondering how to invalidate a certain token 
I'm currently using passport-jwt

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow, please read through the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and rephrase your question. Also add some example code, see the [How to create Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section in the help.

Answer (score 1):

JWT tokens are not supposed to be stored on the server. The token is filled with the users information and signed with a secret key that only the server knows. Once the client sends back the token, your server checks that it's valid by checking the signature using that secret key. Invalidation happens automatically after expiration. If you need to invalidate them manually then you need to defeat the purpose of JWT and store all issued tokens manually on a database.